# Pfx certificate and ksoap2 - android

Tags: android, ssl, ksoap2

i want to connect to web service and i'm using ksoap2. I'm using pfx cert file.

Here is code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream("/pathToFile/cert.pfx"), "password".toCharArray());
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

HttpsTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpsTransportSE("10.10.8.221", 1246, "/WebService?singleWsdl", timeOut);
((HttpsServiceConnectionSE) httpTransport.getServiceConnection()).setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

And when i'm running

```
httpTransport.call("...
```

I get following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Any advise?

Comment: It is not duplicate and accepted answer is of course not valid anymore.